# C, bitmap operation

Tags: c, bitmap, xor, bitwise-xor

I have 3 bitmap arrays and I want to compute a bool result based on below conditions:

```
1) Neighboring even and odd index bits are a pair (the pair relationship will be provided by a bitmap). For example: pair0 = (bit1, bit0); pair1 = (bit3, bit2); etc.

2) For a given bit, if its pair has been already set to 0, then return false; else, return true.
```

For example:

```
Bit index ----------->  3 2 1 0
______________________________________________________________
1) Bitmap#1: 1 1 1 1   1 ? 1 1   (here, "?" could be 0 or 1)
2) Bitmap#2: 0 0 0 0   1 1 0 0
3) Bitmap#3: 0 0 0 0   1 0 0 0
```

In this example, bit3 and bit2 are a pair (see Bitmap#2). Give the bit3 is 1 (see Bitmap#3), then:

```
1) If bit #2 (the "?") in Bitmap#1 is 0, then return false;
2) If bit #2 (the "?") in Bitmap#1 is 1, then return true;
```

How do I use bit operation to calculate the result?

thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? How did your attempt work or not work? Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

This pseudocode shows, how you can test a 2 bit pair for any result. You can use pair 0..3 in an 8-bit bitmap;

```
unsigned char mask = 0x3;  // 00000011 -> mask for two bits
unsigned int pair=1;       // pair with bit #2 and #3
unsigned char result = (bitmap & (mask<<(pair*2)) // shift the mask pair * 2 bits to left (00001100)
result >>= (pair*2);         // shift result back pair * 2 bits

if(result == 0x3) return both;       // bit #3 and #2 are 1
if(result == 0x2) return onlyleft;   // bit #3 is 1 #2 is 0
if(result == 0x1) return onlyright;  // bit #3 is 0 #2 is 1
if(result == 0x0) return none;       // bit #3 and #2 are 0
```